# Python Arguments not taking $ symbol, how to achieve this?

Tags: python, parsing, arguments, command-line-arguments

Python Code `test.py` :

```
import sys
username = str(sys.argv[1])
password = str(sys.argv[2])
print username, password
```

---

Execution #1 : `python test.py usr@gmail.com pa$$word`

Result #1    : `usr@gmail.com, pa24481word`

Expected #1  : `usr@gmail.com, pa$$word`

---

Execution #2 : `python test.py usr@gmail.com $word@pass`

Result #2    : `usr@gmail.com, @pass`

Expected #2  : `usr@gmail.com, $word@pass`

---

**I just want to get what I pass available as String in my code.**

Machine Details : Python 2.6 on OEL 6.6

If someone can help with a solution which is generic across any OS - it will be great!

Comment: This works fine on Windows. ;)

Comment: @MorganThrapp maybe so, but the `@` won't work.

Comment: @BrentWashburne It works on Windows 10. I just tested.

Comment: Sorry, I'm showing my age. :-)

Comment: It doesn't work in Powershell, but it'll work on the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Python. Your shell is interpreting the value before it passes it to the script; `$` in bash introduces an environment variable.

You would have to surround your parameter with single quotes to prevent this:

```
python test.py usr@gmail.com 'pa$$word'
```

Comment: I tried this, but I had tried this with `"` instead of `'`. Thanks for this.

Comment: or escaping them as `\$` would also work (without `'`).

Comment: @Suddev when passing string between double quotes, your OS interprets it (so it resolves variables) while it does not when using strings between single quotes.